# Should I use a contactor of 9 Amps, 12 Amps, or 18 Amps?

Tags: circuits, contactor

I am developing an hidronic project.

Currently the circuits consists of:

- Water pump 60 watts
- Digital timer 16 amps
- Bipolar Thermal magnetic 6 Amps

The energy comes from the thermal magnetic and there it goes to the digital timer, and the contactor is the one that connects the water pump with the digital timer to protect the last one.

Question:
What type of contactor should  I use a contactor of 9 amps, 12 amps, or 18 amps? Is there any risk to use the wrong one?

Thank you very much !

Comment: You should add the voltage used for the water pump.

Comment: Thermal-magnetic is probably a circuit breaker. The description is really not clear. A 60 watt pump would fin in the palm of your hand. It might be something you would put in a fish tank. The timer could probably operate that directly without a contactor. Voting to close the question as unclear.

Comment: hidronic? Do you mean "hydroponic"?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends if it's AC or DC and what voltage you're running at. I'm going to assume AC 115/120V based on the types of devices you're using.

Therefore, the pump will draw 0.5A (or around there; not factoring in other power calculations).

Your digital timer is *rated* for 16A; that is not the current draw.

Thermal magnetic item; not sure what the item is without more details (maybe a transformer?), but the 6A is again rating not draw.

So any of those will work and there isn't any risk to you (go 9A if you had to choose). However, I would add an inline 2A fuse from the wall to your Thermal magnetic item to protect your equipment during power surges.

Comment: Thank you very much Ziggy, I forgot to add the voltage index, the amount of it is 220V, so it would care even less the contactor that I use isnt that right? The thermal magnetic item is a  common thermal switch.